# ASM: too many memory references for `mov'

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, osdev, intel-syntax

It's me again, I have a new problem in my idt.S file (Intel syntax compiled with gcc). When I try to compile the following code:

```
load_idt:
        mov edx, (esp + 4) ; On this line
        lidt (edx)
        sti
        ret
```

I get an error that I really don't know how to fix:

```
Error: too many memory references for `mov'
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are assembling with GCC using something like:

```
gcc -c -m32 -masm=intel idt.S -o idt.o
```

The problems are:

- You will need to add the directive `.intel_syntax noprefix` to the top of your file. By default GCC assembles `.s` and `.S` files assuming Intel syntax requires the `%` prefix on all the registers. That directive eliminates that requirement.
- In Intel syntax memory operands use square brackets `[` and `]` rather than parentheses `(` and `)`.
- Comments start with `#` instead of `;`.

The code should look like:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix

load_idt:
        mov edx, [esp + 4] # On this line
        lidt [edx]
        sti
        ret
```